# Get the value of a constant in a file

Tags: php

```
$file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/log.txt";

$current = file_get_contents($file);
```

There is a `constant` named `TEST` in the file, how do I get its `value`?

```
define("TEST", "Hello you.", true);
```

Comment: Where is the `TEST` constant declared? in `log.txt` ?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant content of `log.txt`?

Comment: Can you copy / paste the relevant content of log.txt file? Then we would be able to help you parse the TEST value.

Comment: define("TEST", "Hello you.", true);

Comment: Read in the line as a string, cut out `define("TEST", "` and `", true);` (`str_replace` with an empty string), `Hello you.` remains - the value. Or use a regexp

Answer (score 2):

If your PHP file contains a constant declared above the code you posted then just use the constant with it's name:

```php
define("TEST", "Hello you.", true);

$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/log.txt';

$file_content = file_get_contents($file);

// To access a constant just type it's name:
echo TEST;
```

If your `TEST` constant is declared in `log.txt` then it's different.

*log.txt*:

```
ASDLFJS SDFWQERSDF sadf sdfwer
asdflkwer
define("TEST", 'This is the content');
another log line
```

You'll need to write a regular expression to get the `define()` declaration, as it may contain a string, a number or whatever. I would use this regex: `/define\((["'])TEST\1[^\n\r]*\)\s*;/`

Test and explanation of the regex: https://regex101.com/r/RoC7dP/2

Once the `define()` declaration is extracted, you could execute it with `eval()` in order to have the constant available. Doing a `require()` or `include()` doesn't seem to be the solution as your file is called `log.txt`, letting me think that it's not a PHP file.

Back to the PHP code:

```php
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/log.txt';

$file_content = file_get_contents($file);

$regex = '/define\((["\'])TEST\1[^\n\r]*\)\s*;/';

if (preg_match($regex, $file_content, $matches)) {
    // This could cause an error.
    // The 3rd argument of define() isn't always accepted.
    eval($matches[0]);
    echo TEST;
} else {
    die('Could not find the TEST declaration!');
}
```

Example of execution here (without a file but just a string because we cannot do it on online compilers): https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/e768f

Answer (score 0):

### Use the include or require functions

The file has the `.txt` extension, but that doesn't matter if it is still PHP code. Some frameworks use `.inc` and other extensions. The file must have `<?php` at the beginning or `<?` if short php tags are allowed.

You can load files as PHP code with the include or require functions:

- [include()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
  Include file (interpret as PHP code) into the current script
- [include_once()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)
  Interprets the file, but that exact file will only be included once if you include that file again. Including the file again will not throw an error.
- [require()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)
  Require will throw an error if the file does not exist
- [require_once()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)
  **Recommended for this:** Throws an error if the file does not exist, will not load that file again if required again. Requiring that file again will not throw an error.

You probably want to keep that define around for as long as the script runs, so `require_once()` is most likely the correct choice for you.

You use the constant as you would by just typing its name: `TEST`.
So for example `var_dump(TEST);`.

Comment: `log.txt` doesn't sound like it has `<?php` at the beginning. And OP only wants to get _the value_ of that constant, not define it

Comment: log.txt doesn't sound like it has PHP source code in it as well, just laying down the options, while I think the other answer will be more complex but better. I'll also add how to access the constant then, ok.